# When invoking SetPassword i receive the error: “Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.”

Tags: c#, active-directory

the set password is failed in the server.

`Exception.message:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)`

Why then will this call work from a local (developer) machine, but not
work from a server?

```
     `      DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(..);
            entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            search.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + userName_ + "))";
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = search.FindAll()[0].GetDirectoryEntry();
            userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] {password@12345#"
            userEntry.CommitChanges();`
```

EDIT : InnerException is {"The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"}

Comment: What's the InnerException?

Comment: TargetInvocationExceptions are usually pretty useless without the inner exception. It's probably got something to do with your invoke though since it's a TargetInvocationException.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/04/29/changepassword-method-may-fail-with-targetinvocationexception-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does the app run under the same account in both environments?  If not, then per your question, it may be a permissions issue

Comment: what kind of permission issue ? if there is a permission problem, how it is working in local machine ?

Comment: @EmreYardımcı only if the program is running as an administrator can it call `SetPassword`, if you do `Run As Administrator` to start the program up dose it work then? I would put in [the program's manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) file `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` so it does that request for you.

Comment: @Emre - are the accounts that run the app locally and on the server, different?  If yes, then you'll need to determine what rights your local account has that the server account doesn't - perhaps domain rights, etc.  Also note the link Millie Smith posted to help you view the inner exception.  This may give you more detail on the problem

Comment: inner exception is {"The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"}

Comment: @Emre - hmmm...is the `Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service` running?  Is there a firewall between these machines?

Comment: probably there is a firewall between my computer and server. my website run on the server so this server has a firewall but i already turn off firewall

Comment: how can i check Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service is running